# tvOS SwiftUI Focus Engine

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tvos, focus-engine

I am facing a decision regarding use SwiftUI in our new tvOS app but I found problem with foucs. I know that exist something like:

```
func focusable(_ isFocusable: Bool = true, onFocusChange: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }) -> some View
```

but I can't see elements like `UIFocusGuide`. Did anyone of You faced similar problem ? Maybe You have any solution / examples how to handle complex focus behaviour in SwiftUI ? Maybe it is not time for using it and we need to wait for new update.

Cheers.

Comment: i am not sure what now really your problem is?

Comment: My problem is that I cannot see support for UIFocusGuides in SwiftUI and it blocks a bit custom, complex focus behaviours

Comment: Maybe it is not time, or you can try to mix them, UIKit is not going to die.

Comment: show us some piece of code with explanation what do you expect and what is current (unexpected) behavior.